# vkAPI. Как получить имена и фамилии всех людей из списка json?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Продолжаю писать бота. Получаю список людей в чёрном списке. Нужно вывести весь список (35 имён, фамилий и их состояние страницы(deactivated)), помогите пожалуйста!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEEsg.jpg)

Нужно вывести в формате: Имя Фамилия
весь список

Comment: > Вывести
А в каком формате-то вывести нужно? У Вас ведь есть готовый словарь.

Comment: shinoxzu дополнил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for user in response["response"]["profiles"]:
    print(f"Имя: {user["first_name"]}")
    print(f"Фамилия: {user["last_name"]}")
    print(f"Аккаунт деактивирован: {"да" if "deactivated" in user else "нет"}")
```

Что-то такое?